# remove array item from nested map object in firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I am trying to figure out how i would go about removing and adding to the profile array in the array of objects. I have the id's to get to the appropriate items in the arrays but it looks like i can only update the entire root array item.

```
doc().update({
    technologyLearned: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove("?")
});
```

if this was a normal language i could technologyLearned[id].profiles[profileid] and get to the item i need to remove or add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't index into an array to locate an item to remove, you will have to read the entire document, modify the array in memory, then write it back to the document.

The problem here is that `technologiesLearned` is an array (not that `profiles` is an array).  If `profiles` was **not** nested under `technologiesLearned` array, you could use `arrayRemove` on it.

Comment: Ya im not sure a better way to structure it, a list of id's that have a list of ids essentially.

Comment: If i did a map with key = id and value = array of the profile id's i think that would also work. There will only be a few hundred technologies and less than a few hundred profiles per tech.

I could then reference the map key and update the array easier right ?

Comment: Yes, you could do that.